# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bert' even after pip install bert-tensorflow and pip install bert-for-tf2

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, bert-language-model

I have tensorflow 1.9.0 and after successful installation of bert using !pip install bert-tensorflow, I cannot import bert in Jupyter notebook. I even ran !pip install bert-for-tf2. Still no success.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I did not have tensorflow in my environment. Fixed after installing tensorflow.